# How to list installed features of Windows Server 2008 in c#

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008

How can I list all installed features of Windows Server 2008 in c#. I tried to query `dism.exe` or `oclist.exe` but not all versions have it. Can I use `System.Management.ManagementClass` to do this somehow ?

Comment: I guess there must be registry nodes you can check for it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found it, you have to use Win32_ServerFeature Class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280268(VS.85).aspx) and  System.Management.ManagementClass. It works on ws2008.

```
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass(
            "Win32_ServerFeature");
ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{
    string featureName = (string)objMO.Properties["Name"].Value;

}
```