# enable roles in windows 2008 from C# code

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008

Is there a way to enable windows server 2008 roles from C# code?

My goal is to enable active directory lightweight directory services role.

Comment: Generally, you do this once and you're finished. There are better ways of automated server management than writing your own C# application from scratch. What's your use case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038901/how-to-list-installed-features-of-windows-server-2008-in-c-sharp) and see if it helps.

Or

You can use Process.Start and use [servermanagercommand](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/install-windows-server-2008-features-with-servermanagercmd/294) to enable/disable features.