# Is there a c# api for DISM commands to get windows package features?

Tags: c#, windows, package

I know you can get a list of all windows package features and if they are enabled or not via command line using this:

```
dism /online /get-features /format:table
```

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent c# api for this? It's not a huge deal if there isn't but it would be nice to not have to spawn dism from my application and parse its output.

Comment: wimgapi, I think: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd834960.aspx

Comment: Looks like someone answered the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038901/how-to-list-installed-features-of-windows-server-2008-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[DllImport("DismApi.dll")]` and call the into the [Dism Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824759.aspx) directly to retrieve package information.

```
[DllImport("dismapi.dll")]
public static extern int DismGetPackages(uint Session, out IntPtr PackageBufPtr, out uint PackageCount);
```

[Windows App Boss](http://windowsappboss.codeplex.com/) does this to add and remove provisioned Windows Store apps, if you want to look at the source of the `WindowsAppBoss.Services.Packages.DismPackageManager` class. You need to initialize and open a session with Dism before requesting informationf from dism.  Also, you will need to run the code as administrator.